# IR frequency counter

Tags: infrared, photodiode, tv, remote

I want to deign a frequency counter in this way:

A specific frequency (33 kHz) is radiated by an infrared transmitter from a distance of 10 m to the infrared receiver for 100 ms.

After amplifying the received signal and converting it into an electric pulse, the receiver circuit sends the pulse signal to the microcontroller and the microcontroller activates a sound output if the received wave is correctly counted (33 kHz).

For this purpose, I designed the following circuit.
[image]

With this circuit, I get the desired result up to a distance of about 3 m, but at longer distances, the work becomes difficult and the transmitter and receiver sensors must be exactly facing each other at an exact angle, which is very difficult to adjust.

How can I design a good infrared receiver so that I can count the radiated wave from a long distance and at a wide angle, like a TV remote control receiver?

The problem is that I must use 2-pin photodiodes and I can't use a 3-pin IR like the HS0038A2.

Comment: My question is, why do you specifically need or want to count the carrier wave pulses? Because usually no one is interested in the carrier wave pulse count, but the data they encode.

Comment: Due to the limited space for the PCB, I have to remove the decoder and encoder circuit elements.
And in order to reduce costs, I have to use cheap 2-pin photodiodes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: _"The problem is that I must use 2-pin photodiodes and I can't use a 3-pin IR like the HS0038A2"_ Why? Use the correct parts for the job.

Comment: My obvious question and problem is how can I design a good infrared receiver using a photodiode so that I can count the radiated wave from a long distance and at a wide angle.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, due to the space limitation for the PCB and the special shape of the designed body, I cannot use 3-pin IR like the HS0038A2.

Comment: This seems to be more a problem of the transmission and reception angles, which would be an optical rather than electronic problem.

Comment: Use a TIA followed by a high-pass filter before the schmitt trigger.

Comment: Through experiments and tests, I realized that part of the problem is related to the optical angles and part is related to the design of the amplifier.
I could not get the desired result by adding the TIA block.

Comment: Then mention the space and mechanical limitations. The number of pins is irrelevant.

Comment: In dimensions of 10 cm long, 1.8 cm wide and 2 cm deep.
The maximum possible dimensions for the PCB is 1.6 cm x 9 cm.

Comment: *I could not get the desired result by adding the TIA block* <-- a TIA is superior in all respects compared to a simple biased photodiode. You may not have designed it to suit your requirements @HosseinAmeri

Comment: Yes, it is true and I also know that part of the problem is due to the design of the bias circuit.
If possible mention the things that I should consider in TIA circuit design. @Andyaka

Comment: I think you should investigate TV remcon receiver chips. They operate at close to 33 kHz (38 kHz) so maybe you could adjust your TX signal.

Comment: Most integrated **IR receivers** include a *demodulator*. Your stated requirement wants **no** demodulator, just an amplifier of raw 33 kHz carrier. Few chips are available for this, but one is **TSMP97000** (a complete amplifier/comparator equivalent of OP's circuit diagram). Otherwise, follow @Andyaka advice, and investigate transimpedance amplifier using a fast opamp.

Comment: What photodiode are you using? What do the optics on the transmitter look like? There are a lot of ways to improve your design (better transmitter, photodiode, and receiver).

Comment: This circuit is supposed to be part of a protection system. The goal I am looking for in the design of this circuit is to be able to detect an obstacle of approximately half the size of a palm between the transmitter and the receiver. According to the tests performed with 2-pin photodiode and 3-pin receivers that have internal demodulators such as HS0038A2, the 3-pin receiver cannot detect an obstacle with small dimensions, that is, a transmitter and receiver that are almost linear are needed. face each other, which is achieved by using a photodiode. @user1850479

Comment: If I use TIA, how can I remove the effect of sunlight? In the previous design I had, when the sunlight was shining in the environment, the amplifier went into saturation and could not amplify the oscillations. @Andyaka

Comment: You employ a feedback system around the op-amp that produces a high degree of negative feedback at DC. Look for a design on-line that uses a TIA and feedback integrator.

Comment: @HosseinAmeri That didn't answer either of my questions. What photodiode are you using (this is an important to know)? What do the optics on the transmitter look like (this will limit your maximum range)?  If I knew more about this I could suggest solutions for sunlight.

Comment: Because I need it to detect an obstacle about half the size of a palm between the transmitter and the receiver. According to tests performed with 2-pin photodiode and 3-pin receivers that have an internal demodulator such as the HS0038A2, the 3-pin receiver cannot detect small-sized obstacles, meaning a nearly linear transceiver is required. face each other, which is achieved by using photodiodes.
Do you think there is another way to do this besides using optics? @user1850479

Comment: What is the model of photodiode you tested with?

Comment: ST-5L5B @user1850479

Comment: Google says that is a phototransistor not a photodiode. The datasheet doesn't specify the active area, but it is probably very small which is why it's so sensitive to angle. It does at least have a visible light filter. If you need linearity, a larger photodiode and a transimpedance amplifier would be a better choice. You could also add a filter for visible light.